# Regular expression that matches specific pattern with range

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string matches a pattern of 1-2 letters, 1-4 digits, and 1 letter. (Examples: *CC44C*, *C4444C*).

I understand that `str.matches("^[A-Z]{2}\\d{4}[A-Z]{1}")` would match a pattern of 2 letters, 4 digits, and 1 letter exactly. (Example: *CC4444C*)

**But how do I make it so it can match a pattern with a range (ie. 1-2 letters, 1-4 digits)?**

I've tried `str.matches("^[A-Z]{1-2}\\d{1-4}[A-Z]{1}")`, but it gives me the following error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index 8
^[A-Z]{2-3}\d{1-4}[A-Z]{1}
```

Comment: You're looking for `{1,4}`.

Comment: `{1,4}` for range 1-4, `{1,}` for *at least one*

Comment: Did you even *bother* to look at a regex guide to see what the `x{n}` syntax is, and what variations there are? E.g. https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change {1-2} to {1,2}, you could understand this as {minimun, maximum}.
Please run the below example and view the result.

```
public class RegularExpression {

public static void main(String[] ar) {
    String str1 = "CC44C";
    String str2 = "C4444C";
    String str3 = "4444C";
    String str4 = "SDFSD123C";
    String pattern = "^[A-Z]{1,2}\\d{1,4}[A-Z]{1}";
    System.out.println(str1+" matches?: "+str1.matches(pattern));
    System.out.println(str2+" matches?: "+str2.matches(pattern));
    System.out.println(str3+" matches?: "+str3.matches(pattern));
    System.out.println(str4+" matches?: "+str4.matches(pattern));
}
```

}

Additionally, if you do not know the maximum, you could use {1,}.

```
    String newPattern = "^[A-Za-z]{1,}\\d{1,}[A-Za-z]{1,}";
```

You could change the pattern above to newPattern and view the result.

Hopefully this could help you :)